# What is the easiest way to sort maps according to values in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, hashtable

I want my hash to sort in descending order according to the values. How do I do that in Java?

Comment: can you be more specific about your problem?  the may be an alternative to sorting by value, depending on your actual problem.

Answer (score 13):

A [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (and its legacy predecesor [`Hashtable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)) is by nature unordered. Even if you sort it, it will remain unordered. If you want to maintain insertion order, then use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead. If you want an automatic sort on **keys**, regardless of insertion order, then use [`SortedMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) instead.

If you want to sort a `Map` on **values**, then you basically need to put the key/value pairs in another kind of a sortable data structure, e.g. `List<Entry<K, V>>`, then sort it using `Collections#sort()` with help of a `Compatator<Entry<K, V>>` and finally repopulate a `LinkedHashMap` with it (not a `HashMap` or you will lose the ordering again).

Here's a basic example (leaving obvious runtime exception handling aside):

```
// Prepare.
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("foo", "bar");
map.put("bar", "waa");
map.put("waa", "foo");
System.out.println(map); // My JVM shows {waa=foo, foo=bar, bar=waa}

// Get entries and sort them.
List<Entry<String, String>> entries = new ArrayList<Entry<String, String>>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry<String, String>>() {
    public int compare(Entry<String, String> e1, Entry<String, String> e2) {
        return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
    }
});

// Put entries back in an ordered map.
Map<String, String> orderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : entries) {
    orderedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

System.out.println(orderedMap); // {foo=bar, waa=foo, bar=waa}
```

To sort it **descencing**, use the following `Comparator`. Basically just swap the entries to compare:

```
Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry<String, String>>() {
    public int compare(Entry<String, String> e1, Entry<String, String> e2) {
        return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue()); // Sorts descending.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Collections.reverseOrder()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder()).

Comment: I think the difficult bit with the question is "according to the values", not "descending"

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
Comparator<K> valueComparator =  new Comparator<K>() {
    public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
        int compare = map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
        if (compare == 0) return 1;
        else return compare;
    }
};
Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
sortedByValues.putAll(map);
return sortedByValues;
```

}